# Clean up request on unanswered questions

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I'm hoping to do some spring cleaning (well it's spring in Australia) and if anyone has a few minutes, to go through the close queue (if you have rights) or the unanswered questions, and see if any should get a close vote from you for being too broad, opinion driven, or off topic as per the rules.

Even better, if they're on topic and you can answer them, that'd be great too.

Our [beta site stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates) are doing reasonably well, but we're definitely lacking in the answer percentage - currently at 79%.

So if you can spend just 10 minutes, and see what you can do to help with that, it'd be really great.

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Just want to add that if you can answer the questions with quality/useful information, that's even better and achieves the same effect of getting our answer percentage bumped up.

Comment: @ouflak yeah you mean as stated in my second paragraph? ;) But yeah, we should only be closing unanswerable ones - and answering on topic, quality ones.